# Ignore home directory in Mod_Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm waiting to rewrite a domain like this: `http://domain.com/USER` o a domain like this `http://domain.com/viewer/user.php?username=USER`.

But if the username is blank, then ignore the rule and keep it on the homepage.

Here's what I have now:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /viewer/user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

But it's treating the home page as a user.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, this was the subdirectory. Interesting, reveal the subdirectory so I can check it out. Maybe even beta test (*hint hint*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !user\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)           [NC]
RewriteRule  .*    viewer/user.php?username=%1  [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://domain.com/USER`

To:

`http://domain.com/viewer/user.php?username=USER`

`viewer` and `user.php` are fixed strings, while `USER` is not and can be any name.